# The set of vectors perpendicular to some fixed $y \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\}$ has Lebesgue measure greater than $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

This is part of a proof I am trying to solve, but I got stuck. Part of the problem is to prove that, for some fixed $y \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\}$ $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1 - \cos(x \cdot y)}{|x|^{n + q}} > 0$$

I was planning on using the theorem that says that says that, for $f$ measurable and non-negative, if $\int_X f(x) \mathrm{d}\mu = 0$ then $f = 0$ almost everywhere.

Therefore, if $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1 - \cos(x \cdot y)}{|x|^{n + q}} = 0$, then we should have $1 - \cos(x \cdot y) = 0$ which is true iff $x \cdot y = 0$ a.e. iff $x \perp y$ a.e.

Then, I tried to prove that $m_n(\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:x \perp y\}) = 0$ which would mean that it is not true that $x \perp y$ almost everywhere, but I can't prove this last part.

What I did so far was:

Rotate the coordinate system in a way that leaves $y$ paralell to the $x_1$-axis. Therefore, the set of vectors perpendicular to $x_1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is the set of ordered $n$-tuples 
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x = (0,x_2,...,x_n)\} = \{0\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$$

Therefore,

$$m_n(\{0\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}) = m_1(\{0\}) m_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n-1}) = 0 \cdot \infty = 0 \text{ (at least in measure theory)}$$

Is this acceptable?

Comment: The $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure is going to be $0$. You can cover the set of perpendicular vectors by a union of boxes with total volume as small as you want. Let $v_1,v_2,...,v_{n-1},y$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $v_1,...,v_n$ perpendicular to $y$. In coordinates in this basis define $B_k=\{(x_1,...,x_n): max(|x_1|,...,|x_{n-1}|)<k, |x_n|<2^{-M-n}k^{-n+1}\}$. Then the volume of $B_n=2^{-M-n}$. The union of the $B_k$ cover the set of vectors perpendicular to $y$ and the sum of their volumes is $2^{-M}$, which can be made as small as you want.

Comment: Pictorially, in dimension 2, you're asking to show that a line has positive 2D measure, which isn't true

Comment: I am sorry, I phrased my question completely wrong. With your comment I noticed the mistake and I added more context and a better explanation.

Comment: You don't need this. First without loss of generality $y=(1,0,\dots,0)$. (this is due to the rotation invariance of the Lebesgue measure and the function $|x|$, and scaling doesn't affect positivity) Now the integrand is non-negative and it is strictly positive on a small ball around $x=y$ say radius $1/2$, proving the result. There's a range of $q$ for whether the integral is $+\infty$ or strictly smaller, but that's not related to what you wrote

Comment: Thank you. I still came up with some other proof. I am not sure it is correct though. I updated my post. Thank you!

Comment: If you must proceed in that manner, I would suggest you remove all doubt by avoiding multiplying the measures like that, you can instead use the proof of user conditionalMethod

Comment: What is the reason? Is it ambiguous due to the $0 \times \infty$ part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100262/discussion-between-the-bosco-and-calvin-khor).